# how to make nginx and apache work together for showing the real client IP?

Tags: apache, proxy, nginx

I'm trying to configure an apache server behind a nginx proxy.
The nginx and apache instances are on two different hosts. 
Boths servers are running debian squeeze.

I have this in the nginx.conf of the front server (192.168.1.30)

```
 server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name  front.tld.org;  #real hostname changed

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:80;  #local IP of the server running apache
    }
```

On the apache host (192.168.1.1), `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rpaf.conf`:

```
<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
RPAFenable On
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFproxy_ips 192.168.1.30
RPAFheader X-Real-IP
</IfModule>
```

I restarted both nginx and apache2 services. 
However in the apache2 `/var/log/apache2/access.log` I always have an originating IP from 192.168.1.30 (the proxy) instead of the real client.

Is there anything wrong ? Any idea of how to debug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record, there is something strange with Debian squeeze config files.

The following config worked:

```
RPAFenable On
RPAFsethostname On
RPAFproxy_ips 172.27.6.74 172.27.7.17 127.0.0.1 ::1
RPAFheader X-Forwarded-For
```

(I had to remove `<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>`)

Comment: Can confirm this fixed the issue, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What you see at the moment is the correct behavior. Because only your applications (run on Apache) see the real IP. For example, install a sample application such as WordPress and install real-time analytics such as Piwik. Insert the Piwik code in WordPress footer and visit your WordPress site (after logging out). Now the Piwik would show the real IP instead of what is set at RPAFproxy_ips.